# About "Trichotomy Law for Real Numbers"

Tags: proof-verification, real-numbers

I must proof the "Trichotomy Law for Real Numbers":

- **Prop. 1**: let be $\Bbb{R}$ a complete ordered field, then $$\forall x,y \in \Bbb{R}(x=y \vee x < y \vee x > y)$$
- **Proof 1**: by definition of $ \Bbb{R} $, $\geq$ (or $\leq$) is [total relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_relation) therefore $$\forall x,y \in \Bbb{R}(x \geq y \vee x \leq y) $$ but $x \geq y \leftrightarrow x=y \vee x >y$ then $$\forall x,y \in \Bbb{R}(x < y \vee x > y \vee x=y) $$

But (**Prop. 2**) $\forall x,y \in \Bbb{R}$ exactly one of the following holds:

- $x=y$
- $x<y$
- $x>y$

therefore $$\forall x,y \in \Bbb{R}(\mbox{ or } x=y \mbox{ or } x < y \mbox{ or } x > y)$$ where $(\mbox{ or } x=y \mbox{ or } x < y \mbox{ or } x > y)$ is "logically" [CLIC](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20%28not%20p%20and%20%20not%20q%20and%20r%29%20or%20%28p%20and%20%20not%20q%20and%20not%20r%29%20or%20%28not%20p%20and%20%20q%20and%20not%20r%29%20)...

How can I proof the **Prop. 2**? I thought proof the following:

- $x=y \leftrightarrow x \ngtr y \wedge x \nless y$
- $x <y \leftrightarrow x \neq y \wedge x \ngtr y$
- $x>y \leftrightarrow x \neq y \wedge x \nless y$

because [CLIC](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20%28not%20p%20and%20%20not%20q%20and%20r%29%20or%20%28p%20and%20%20not%20q%20and%20not%20r%29%20or%20%28not%20p%20and%20%20q%20and%20not%20r%29%20) is equivalente to [eq_CLIC](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=truth%20table%20%28p%20%3C-%3E%20%28not%20q%20and%20not%20r%29%29%20and%20%28q%20%3C-%3E%20%28not%20p%20and%20not%20r%29%29%20and%20%28r%20%3C-%3E%20%28not%20p%20and%20not%20q%29%29)

Is it correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at it like so:

- $x=y \leftrightarrow (x \le y \wedge y \le x)$
- $x<y \leftrightarrow x \le y \wedge \neg(x \le y \wedge y \le x)$
- $x>y \leftrightarrow y \le x \wedge \neg(x \le y \wedge y \le x)$

Combining any two will yield a $(x \le y \wedge y \le x)$ and a $\neg(x \le y \wedge y \le x)$

Also since $\le$ is a total relation, if $(x \le y \wedge y \le x)$ is false, one of the last two must be true. Hence at least one of three is true.

Comment: thanks soo much. :) I edited my post, It is correct?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by CLIC. Anyway I added the missing half of the argument to my answer.